# Failed to update database "Adventure Works 2012" because the database is read-only

Tags: sql-server

Failed to update database "Adventure Works 2012" because the database is read-only. using sql server 2012

Comment: Are you *asking* us something, or *telling* us something?

Comment: You need to specifically ASK a question. What are you tryign to do? what did you do? what produced this message?

Comment: The problem is that the database is read-only. That's why you failed to update the database.

Comment: You could have googled `sql server database read only` and i see the top result has your answer.

Comment: You could have duckduckgoed `sql server database read only` and I see the top result has your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are being incredibly vague with your question but you should be able to use:

`ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks] SET READ_WRITE`